# How to eliminate this SQL String_Split function error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to use the SQL string_split function in a dynamic query but I continue to receive the following error.
Invalid column name 'Invoice Description'.
Argument data type void type is invalid for argument 1 of string_split function.
I can not figure out the issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
DECLARE @AuthFile nvarchar(max); DECLARE @TableName AS SYSNAME;
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SET @TableName = '__tTransactions_' + REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103), '/', '');
SET @AuthFile = '__Authorization';

create table #temp (TransactionID nvarchar(1000), CartID int, TotalAmount nvarchar(1000))

SET @sql = 'select [Transaction ID] as TransactionID, cs.value as CartID, [Total Amount] as TotalAmount 
            into #temp 
            from ' + @TableName + '
            cross apply string_split([Invoice Description], ''|'') cs
            where (isnull([Invoice Description], '''') <> '''')';

print(@sql);
EXEC(@sql);
SET @sql = '';

select * from #temp

drop table #temp
```

Comment: I would suggest that you supply sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what the code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: String Split doesnt work on some data types and as a result you have to cast the data type to something it can use. My assumption youre using varchar(max) or some other data type thats treated like a blob at times. Let us know what that data type is and whether or not CAST() to varhcar(8000) fixes it for you.

Comment: If I take this query out of the variable and run it not as a dynamic query, it work just fine.

Comment: "void type" sounds a bit weird. Don't know why it doesn't say the actual datatype. You would see this if `__tTransactions_05042021` doesn't contain column `Invoice Description` at all - but also along with other errors for `Invalid column name 'Invoice Description'`

Comment: In any event you don't want to be using `SELECT ...INTO` here as this will create a new temporary table in the scope of the dynamic SQL that is destroyed as soon as that exits

Comment: The column does exist in the table as nvarchar(255)

Comment: The only reason I had to do it this way was to avoid typing @TableName multiple times. I guess I will remove it as dynamic query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample table can be created to run your dynamic sql against.

```
drop table if exists #__tTransactions_05042021;
create table #__tTransactions_05042021 (
    [Transaction ID] int, 
    [Total Amount] float,
    [Invoice Description] varchar(255)
);
insert #__tTransactions_05042021 values 
    (1, 100, '1|2|3'),
    (2, 200, '4|5|6')
```

This sample is a temp table, so I changed your code to point to a temp table instead of a real one, but otherwise it's the same:

```
DECLARE @AuthFile nvarchar(max); 
DECLARE @TableName AS SYSNAME;
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SET @TableName = '#__tTransactions_' + REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103), '/', '');
SET @AuthFile = '__Authorization';

create table #temp (TransactionID nvarchar(1000), CartID int, TotalAmount nvarchar(1000))

SET @sql = 'select [Transaction ID] as TransactionID, cs.value as CartID, [Total Amount] as TotalAmount 
            into #temp 
            from ' + @TableName + '
            cross apply string_split([Invoice Description], ''|'') cs
            where (isnull([Invoice Description], '''') <> '''')';

print(@sql);
EXEC(@sql);
SET @sql = '';

select * from #temp

drop table #temp;
```

This code does NOT error out.  It's not the code.  It's the structure of the table you're pointing to.  See what table is targeted in your from clause that's printed out, and look at the table structure.  You should find that it doesn't have an 'invoice description' column.

Now, there are more issues with your code.  Namely, you're trying to pump your data into '#temp' inside dynamic sql.  Your code won't fail, but it won't work either because the context is different between code inside dynamic sql and the code outside of it.

You'll want to either use a global temp table (i.e. ##temp) or use insert-exec.  Below is how you would change the last part of your code to do the latter:

```
create table #temp (TransactionID nvarchar(1000), CartID int, TotalAmount nvarchar(1000))

SET @sql = 'select [Transaction ID] as TransactionID, cs.value as CartID, [Total Amount] as TotalAmount 
            from ' + @TableName + '
            cross apply string_split([Invoice Description], ''|'') cs
            where (isnull([Invoice Description], '''') <> '''')';

print(@sql);
insert #temp
EXEC(@sql);
SET @sql = '';
```